# Problem of "Attempt to assign property 'otp_expires_time' of non-object" . How to solve this in Laravel 8x?

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, request, laravel-8, one-time-password

I am trying to expire OTP number, but it shows me that there is an issue with "Attempt to assign property 'otp_expires_time' of non-object". Can anyone help me ?

**Here is a part of my code**

```
              $otp = rand(100000,999999);
              $otp->otp_expires_time = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(20);
  //            Cache::put([$otp], now()->addSeconds(20));

    //          $otp_expires_time = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(20);
    //        $otp_expires_time = Cache::put(['otp' => $otp], now()->addSeconds(20));
              Log::info("otp = ".$otp);

              $user = User::where('phonenumber', $request->phonenumber)->update(['otp' => $otp]);
```

Comment: The error messages says it all: `$otp` is not an object. (It's a random number)

Comment: Yes but how can i set expire otp?